# Multiple div height columns on row using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What approach can I take when I want to include multiple classes within a JQuery same height script?

I currently have four different divs classed as '.row-16' and it works perfectly, but how can I add more groups to this specific script?

I want to include .row-1 .row-2 etc..

***Sorry for the confusion, but this is ultimately what I'm trying to achieve.

.row-1 has four columns that will all be the same height size depending on highest.

.row-2 will be separate from row-1 and will have it's own equal height columns.***

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fLr9th4y/3/ - Working example on Row-11

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.container').each(function(){  
    var highestBox = 0;

    $(this).find('.row-16').each(function(){
        if($(this).height() > highestBox){  
            highestBox = $(this).height();  
        }
    })

    $(this).find('.row-16').height(highestBox);
    });    
});
```

The above script currently aligns all four of my columns with the correct height, I just want to add more class groups.

Comment: Wrap your current code in a function that accepts `.row-16` as parameter instead of hardcoding it. Then call the function once for each class.

Comment: @ChrisG, It would be easier to do it the proper grid bootstrap way, but I have a complicated table with columns with 15+ rows inside so the slick carousel works

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/fLr9th4y/2/ - I would like each row to have it's own equal height size.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fLr9th4y/3/

Comment: I understand what you want and told you how to achieve it. Not sure how your comment addresses my suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Why not adding a new class, specifically for the elements that should have their height changed and target that? BTW, here is a similar script that I used a couple of years ago for such occasions.

```
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
/**
 * Equalize the height of the given items.
 * @type {*|jQuery}
 * @return mixed
 * @param options
 * Example: $('.item1, .item2').equalHeight({ container: '.container' });
 */
$.fn.equalHeight = function (options) {
    var items, settings;
    items = this;
    settings = $.extend({
        container: ''
    }, options);
    if (settings.container) {
        // If a container is set, apply setHeight() for all containers.
        $(settings.container).each(function () {
            var thisC = $(this),
                getItems = [];
            $.each(items, function (index, value) {
                getItems.push(thisC.find(value));
            });
            return setHeight(getItems);
        });
    } else {
        // Otherwise we assume that the items exist only once in a page
        // and we apply setHeight() to their first (and unique) instance.
        return setHeight(this);
    }
    // Set the height of all items equal to the highest item.
    function setHeight(getItems) {
        var itemsH = [];
        $(getItems).each(function () {
            itemsH.push($(this).outerHeight());
        });
        var maxH = Math.max.apply(Math, itemsH);
        $(getItems).each(function () {
            return $(this).css('height', maxH);
        });
    }
}
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

([Demo](https://codepen.io/gsarig/pen/wRqRPy))

Of course, I don't need it anymore, thanks to [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container').each(function() {
        var highestBox16 = 0;
        var highestBox1 = 0;
        var highestBox2 = 0;
        var highestBox3 = 0;
        //var highestBox..

        $(this).find('.row-16,.row-1,.row-2,.row-3').each(function() {
            if($(this).hasClass('row-16')){
                if ($(this).height() > highestBox16) {
                    highestBox16 = $(this).height();
                }
            }
            if($(this).hasClass('row-1')){
                if ($(this).height() > highestBox1) {
                    highestBox1 = $(this).height();
                }
            }
            if($(this).hasClass('row-2')){
                if ($(this).height() > highestBox2) {
                    highestBox2 = $(this).height();
                }
            }
            if($(this).hasClass('row-3')){
                if ($(this).height() > highestBox3) {
                    highestBox3 = $(this).height();
                }
            }
        })
        $('.row-16,.row-1,.row-2,.row-3').height(highestBox);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hernandez, this is great but I do apologize! I meant that each .row- will have it's own size grouped and not all the same size.

So like .row-1 will be grouped all same column height and then .row-2 will be separate group.

Answer (score 0):

This should select each class that starts with "row", then get each unique one and then get the max height for each class and set all those to the max of the largest.

Per the question update, using the question and fiddle for possible answer using a given "row-" begins with, which does not seem to be in the fiddle but is in the question.

```js
var myselector = 'row-';

function getRowMax(row) {
  var heights = $(row).map(function() {
    return $(this).height();
  }).get();

  var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
  return maxHeight;
}

function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

function getrow(value, index, self) {
  return value.startsWith(myselector);
}

$(function() {
  var rows = $('.container').find("[class^='" + myselector + "']");
  var classListAll = [];
  rows.each(function(item) {
    var classes = item.attr('class').split(/\s+/);
    classListAll.concat(classes);
  });
 // var classListAll = rows.attr('class').split(/\s+/);
  var classList = classListAll.filter(onlyUnique).filter(getrow);
  $.each(classList, function(index, item) {
    var sel = '.' + item;
    var m = getRowMax(sel);
    $(sel).height(m);
  });
});
```

```css
.heading {
  background-color: #00C6D7;
}

.sub-heading {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
}

h4,
h6 {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.container {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(77, 72, 69, 0.2), 0 6px 10px rgba(77, 72, 69, 0.15);
}

.row>.col-md-12>span {
  font-size: smaller;
}

.col-md-4>.row {
  padding-top: .6rem!important;
  padding-bottom: .6rem!important;
}

.col-md-3>.row {
  padding-top: .6rem!important;
  padding-bottom: .6rem!important;
}

.col-md-2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.col-md-9 {
  padding: 0px!important;
}

.bl {
  border-left: 1px solid lightgray;
}

.bb {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00C6D7;
}

.bg-white {
  background-color: white;
}

.mainText {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #00C6D7;
}

.bg-fhdark {
  background-color: #5E6A71;
}

.title {
  color: #A2AD00;
}

.blank {
  background: transparent!important;
}

.slick-prev,
.slick-next {
  background: black!important;
}

.r1 {
  color: black;
}


/* BootStrap 4 Classes */

.py-5 {
  padding-bottom: 3rem!important;
  padding-top: 3rem!important;
}

.py-2 {
  padding-bottom: .5rem!important;
  padding-top: .5rem!important;
}

.text-white {
  color: #fff!important;
}

.text-left {
  text-align: left!important;
}

.text-uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase!important;
}

.font-weight-bold {
  font-weight: 700!important;
}

.small {
  font-size: 80%;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}


/* ----- */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" />

<body>
  <div class="py-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 text-white text-left py-2 heading">
          <h4 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Core Competencies</h4>
          <span class="small">Our goal was to develop a set of core competencies that are consistent across the agency amd reflect growth as a priority.
                </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-2 text-center py-2 heading">
          <img src="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="row r1">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <span>Test</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row py-1 bg-fhdark">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">
                  <span>Client</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row bb">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <span>Client Focus, Strategic Counsel and Consultancy</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row bb">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <span>Integrated Strategy and Account Management</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <span>Creativity and Innovation</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row py-1 bg-fhdark">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">
                  <span>Talent</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row bb">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <span>Manage Full Talent LifeCycle</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row bb">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <span>Professional Development/Developing and Empowering</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <span>Self-Leadership</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row py-1 bg-fhdark">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">
                  <span>Business Development and Growth</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row bb">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <span>New Business Strategy</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row bb">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <span>Prospecting</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row bb">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <span>New Business Pitch Preparation, Participation and Leadership</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <span>Organic Growth</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row py-1 bg-fhdark">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">
                  <span>Finance and Operations</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row bb">
                <div class="col-md-12 row-11">
                  <span>Financial Management of Accounts (Account Profitability, Realization, Budgets) TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <span>Staffing and Resource Planning</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <section class="regular slider">
                <div class="col-md-4 bl">
                  <div class="row r1">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold title">Junior</h6>
                      <span>Valued Colleague and Practitioner</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bg-fhdark">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>1</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>2</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>3</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bg-fhdark">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>4</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>5</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>6</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bg-fhdark">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>7</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>8</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>9</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>10</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bg-fhdark">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12 row-11">
                      <span>11</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>12</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 bl">
                  <div class="row r1">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold title">Mid</h6>
                      <span>Trusted Colleague; Proven and Creative Practitioner</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bg-fhdark">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>1</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>2</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>3</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bg-fhdark">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>4</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>5</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>6</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bg-fhdark">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>7</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>8</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>9</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>10</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bg-fhdark">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12 row-11">
                      <span>11</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>12</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 bl">
                  <div class="row r1">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold title">Senior</h6>
                      <span>Trusted Client Advisor and Partner; Proven Agency Leader</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bg-fhdark">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>1</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>2</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>3</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bg-fhdark">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>4</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>5</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>6</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bg-fhdark">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>7</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>8</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>9</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>10</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bg-fhdark">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row bb">
                    <div class="col-md-12 row-11">
                      <span>11</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <span>12</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </section>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(".regular").slick({
        dots: false,
        infinite: false,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Mark! I've tried the snippet above and unfortunately, it didn't work and broke the row-16 in place also. I'll be looking into the code and see if I can break it down part by part.

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents I updated it using the fiddle HTML, note I do not see a class with "row-" start in the fiddle but that is the question.